# Wacky battery report -- ghost using my computer at night?

Tags: laptop, battery

Why does my laptop's Battery Report sometimes say that it was **"Active"** when I know I wasn't using the computer and had the lid closed, and sometimes says **"Suspended"** when I was using it? Sometimes it says it was active for hours on end in the middle of the night, when I know I was asleep! Very weird. I thought Active means that the lid is open and the computer is in use, and Suspended means it is closed. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: It is possible you have on of the newer sleep modes in use and the computer was doing updates

Comment: Where do you see this? What is your operating system?

Comment: As john says, this could be [Modern Standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby). On that page: "These longer active intervals occur for a variety of reasons, for example, processing incoming email or downloading critical Windows updates. Windows components that are allowed to leave the SoC in the active power state are called activators because they are registered with the power manager as capable of blocking the transition back to the idle power mode"